# Using Fragment created from one activity in another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, admob

I have a `MainActivity` and a `SubActivity` for app. `MainActivity` has a multiple buttons, on selecting a button, `SubActivity` will be launched with button value. Finally, `SubActivity` will go back to `MainActivity` on success and failure.

Now the problem is i wanted to place an `AdView` for both the activities. Is it possible to have `AdView` in a `Fragment` which can  be used in both `MainActivity` and `SubActivity` without recreating it?

I am working with phone and not using tablet, main intention is "even though there are multiple transition between `MainActivity` and `SubActivity`, i want the `AdView` visible with same add and timing out considering both activities times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Views are tied to the activity which created them. No other activity can display it. The solution for your problem is to have a Fragment with AdView and the MainActivity + SubActivity converted to fragments. Another activity would display the AdView fragment along with MainFragment or SubFragment. Cycling between the two can be done by using fragment transitions.

Comment: This is a good pattern, but it could be worded more clearly. 1. The `AdView` doesn't need to be in a fragment. It could just be a UI element on the `FragmentActivity'. 2. "Cycling between the two" is the two (Main-, Sub-) Fragments.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this, it's correct. The activity can have only 1 placeholder for fragments.

Comment: In my app, MainActivity and SubActivity are quite heavy. By migrating the MainActivity and SubActivity to Fragment based, will there be any overhead in terms of performance?

Comment: No, both of them do the same job - inflate the layout and display it. Performance will be identical.

Answer (score 0):

The better approach should be make a base Activity class and add your AdView inside,

then MainActivity and SubActivity should be extend from BaseActivity.

Comment: By doing this, when creating MainActivity and SubActivity, wont the AdView will be created again?

Comment: @user3037143, you are correct. This answer doesn't solve your problem. azertiti's answer should point you in the right direction.

Comment: If we're talking about Activities, yes it'll create it again but there is no option to not create it and share it with another activity. Converting activities to fragments for adview is not a good option to me unless your activities don't have lots of things inside already.